# Синонимы благодарности

Tags: синонимы

Какие слова кроме "благодарю" и "спасибо" могут выражать это намерение?
Не беря в учёт: мерси, грасиас, сенк'ю и прочего.

Если данный вопрос уже поднимался - будьте добры, укажите тему, по поиску не нашлось ничего требуемого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно распростанить эти 2 слова: *премного вам благодарен, огромное вам спасибо и пр.*

Пожелать добра: *спаси (храни) вас Бог, да пребудет с вами удача (сила) и пр.*

Указать на то, что сам ответишь добром на добро: *теперь я ваш должник, теперь я вам обязан и пр.*

Comment: У сербов, хорватов и словенцев благодарят словом **"хвала"**. 

Для русских это звучит высокопарно и по-старинному, как и некоторые другие *обычные* южно-славянские слова. 

Вот вспомнилось...

.

Для ответа здесь сведений маловато, поэтому оформлю, как комментарий.

Comment: Хвала. Верно, точно по исканиям. Хвала вам! :-]

Answer (score 3):

Однословных русских синонимов не припомню, а из аналитических форм ближе всего "бью челом". Правда эта форма годится и как "спасибо" и как "пожалуйста" (при просьбе).